# Circle ci trigger a build on pull request creation or update

Tags: github, github-api, circleci-2.0

We are usng circle ci and github.

So i have a remote k8 cluster for staging, on which we have our test suite.

I have a project on github, and id like to deploy and run the tests on the cluster everytime a pull request is created or updated. The reason for doing it on pull requests is that we wwant to merge the feature branch with master and then run the tests on the rmeote testing cluster:

I have read a few articles, but nothing that explains to me how this could be achieved.

Github web hooks calling circle ci on pull request creation or update?

Build status based on the result of remote testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible on CircleCI, they do not expose all the payload from a github.

its on their todo list

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible now, just don't specify any branch and it will trigger on every pull requests creation or update.